# How to avoid deleting an allocated memory twice?

Tags: dynamic

For example if I have an object that contains a pointer to a dynamically allocated object, then assign it to another object with the same type, i.e.

```
object2 = object1;
```

and the destructor will explicitly delete the dynamically allocated object. So when object2 and object1 go out of scope, an error will occur (which I assume to be because the address for the dynamically allocated object is deleted twice). So what should I do to fix/avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is C++?  In which case, take a look at [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).  Reference counting (boost::shared_ptr) helps take care of this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid it because you copied all bits of object1 to object2, there will be two pointers to the same place, but the destructor will be called twice, because there are two objects.

The fisrt solution will prevent the call of the destructor of object2:

```
char object2_data[sizeof(object1)];
Type* object2 = (Type*) object2_data;
*object2 = object1;
...
object1.do_something();
object2->do_something(); //However, the pointer is different
```

The second way is to redesign the object and add a bool variable that will tell if the object is a copy. When the object be deleted, if it is a copy, do not delete the pointer. Finally, implement the copy constructor and overload the operator = to copy the object and set the bool variable to tell that it is a copy. However, if the original object be deleted, the copies will not can be used, because they will have invalid pointers.